# How to gray out close button in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, clr

How to gray out the close button in C++? Is it possible?
I tried that;

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include<windows.h>
DeleteMenu(SystemMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
```

But didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here http://www.davekb.com/browse_programming_tips:win32_disable_close_button:txt for how to do it using pure Win32 or using MFCs. All the credit goes to them. I've just written the explanations.

This function will enable or disable (and gray out) the menu option (and, as a side effect, the close button) on Win32:

```
BOOL EnableCloseButton(const HWND hwnd, const BOOL bState)
{
    HMENU   hMenu;
    UINT    dwExtra;

    if (hwnd == NULL) return FALSE;
    if ((hMenu = GetSystemMenu(hwnd, FALSE)) == NULL) return FALSE;
    dwExtra = bState ? MF_ENABLED : (MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED);
    return EnableMenuItem(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND | dwExtra) != -1;
}
```

It takes the HWND of the window and the desired state for the close button (TRUE enabled, FALSE disabled).

For MFC you can use this version, which accepts a CWnd instead of an HWND:

```
BOOL EnableCloseButton(const CWnd *wnd, const BOOL bState)
{
    CMenu *menu;

    if (wnd == NULL) return FALSE;
    if ((menu = wnd->GetSystemMenu(FALSE)) == NULL) return FALSE;
    return menu->EnableMenuItem(SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND | bState ? MF_ENABLED : MF_GRAYED) != -1;
}
```

Comment: I got `C2065: 'hwnd' : undeclared identifier` error for some reason. :l

Comment: Which version are you using? I assume Win32 version. Are you including Windows.h in the file you've defined the function EnableCloseButton()?

Comment: Yep. I am using Win32 version. i included Windows h, added HWND hwnd; code under the class but it didn't worked.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "added HWND hwnd; code under the class"? Can you show us the relevant source code?

Comment: `namespace Tutorial {

 HWND hwnd;` I added `EnableCloseButton(hwnd, FALSE);` under `InitializeComponent();` .

Comment: With only that small amount of code I don't get the whole picture, but the error probably means that the variable or member `hwnd` is not defined for the scope where you're calling `EnableCloseButton(hwnd, FALSE);` (i.e. is not visible from there). That's a different problem than the initial one.